# How to make each node of a graph a button?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, button

A newbie question this one - MMA help seems to suggest it would be possible to place a button on ( or have a button be ) each node of graph, labelled with the name of said node. I have no idea where to start with the syntax for this though...any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you can use [VertexShapeFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexShapeFunction.html) to do it (also take a look at the other options for [Graph](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graph.html)). Modifying one of the examples from the documentation:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> "bob", "bob" -> 1}, VertexShapeFunction -> (Inset[
     Tooltip[
      Button[#2, Speak["vertex " <> ToString[#2]]],
      Column[{"arguments:"}~Join~List@##]], #1] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This is a more general version of **amr**'s button-graph, with hidden button graphics, multiple button actions (print, speak, recolor) and dynamic redrawing (recoloring nodes) to showcase more advanced capabilities of *Mathematica*:

```
(* assign colors to vertices *)
colors = # -> Hue[.6, .2, .8] & /@ {1, 2, "bob"};

Dynamic[Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> "bob", "bob" -> 1}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> (
    {Inset[ActionMenu[
        Graphics[{#2 /. colors, EdgeForm@{GrayLevel[0, .7]}, 
          Disk[#1, .004], Black, Text[#2, #1]}, ImageSize -> 40],
        {
         "Speak" :> Speak@("vertex " <> ToString@#2),
         "Print" :> Print@("vertex " <> ToString@#2),
         "Recolor" :> (colors[[First@First@Position[colors, #2], -1]] = 
            Hue[RandomReal[], .2, 1])
         },
        Appearance -> None], #1]} &
    ), ImageSize -> 250], TrackedSymbols :> {colors}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]